# Table Glitch / Error with binary data

Tags: list-manipulation, binary

I have a large group of binary files that I am loading with

```
binaryList = Table[ BinaryReadList[ paths[[i]], "Byte"], {i, Length@paths}];
```

specifically 1019 files that are 4.5 mb each.  I then use the following to parse through the first binary list in order to extract specific bytes and make a list.

```
headerBytes = Table[ int32bytesToInt@binaryList[[ 1, 12240*(i-1)+185;;12240*(i-1)+188]], {i, 364}]
```

where int32bytesToInt is my function, and each entry of binaryList is actually 364 data streams, 12000 bytes long (with a 240 byte header), all run together (I'm extracting bytes 185 through 188 from the header of each data stream).  The code worked perfectly on smaller data sets (~400 files, 2 mb each) but with this amount of data, the second Table freezes once the 'i' iterator value gets to around 275.  Simply changing from Table to Do and the second step completes like normal.  Additionally, I can do this

```
tempList = binaryList[[1]];
headerBytes = Table[ int32bytestoint[ tempList[[ 12240*(i-1)+185;;12240*(i-1)+188]], {i, 364}]
```

and it also completes like normal (and in about 0.07 seconds).  Why can't I pass the full list to Table without making this tempList?  Is this a problem with Table or am I missing something?

Note that it only freezes once I've loaded over 2 gb of binary data, so I can't easily share this, I'm more interested if I'm using bad practice, or if someone has encountered a similar issue with Table.

Comment: You are not using `i` in your first table so you're feeding all of the paths into BinaryReadList instead of each path one-by-one. You don't need the first Table at all in fact. Do this instead `binaryList = BinaryReadList[#, "Byte"] & /@ paths`.

Comment: I am using 'i', I edited the post.  Agreed on the function form but I don't think thats the issue.

Comment: What is the result of `$SystemWordLength`, `$System`, `$ProcessorType` , `$Version` please ?

Comment: 64,   Mac OS X x86 (64-bit),   x86-64,   12.1.0

Comment: Very likely, this happens at the point where the `Table` is large enough so that it attempts to auto-compile its argument. See `SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength"]` If it is indeed this, it would be a bug. When you suspect a bug, the first thing to do is to ensure that you have the latest bugfix release, i.e. 12.1.1 in this case. Will it fix this? I don't know. But many other bugs *have* been fixed in 12.1.1 and I would not recommend using 12.1.0 anymore.

Comment: Thanks and noted on 12.1.0.  For what it's worth, the ```SystemOptions``` result is ```{CompileOptions -> {TableCompileLength -> 250}}```.  Do you know what are the units for that value of 250?  It seems really low.